# Program output must be a JSON encoded map of string keys and string values.terraform external data complains about

Tags: json, terraform

This is the error i get when triying yo using a external provider to parse a sops file json and use this as data source, to be then converted into yaml and wacked into vault

```
37b40d-39c3-ca0a-5a76-d8a5f44456d8 @module=external output="{
        "AzureAD": {
                "Application ID": "REDACTED",
                "Description": "REDACTED",
                "Secret Id": "REDACTED",
                "Value": "REDACTED"
        }
}"
```

and this the terraform code:

```
data "external" "sops_to_yaml" {

  program = ["bash", "scripts/sops_decode.sh"]
  query = {
    file = "${path.module}/secrets/account_secrets_testing.json"
  }
}


output "secret_output" {

  value = [for k, v in nonsensitive(data.external.sops_to_yaml.result) : "key=${k} | value=${v} "]

}
```

and this the script

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script will open the sops file and read it as json
# Step#1 - Parse the input
eval "$(jq -r '@sh "file=\(.file)"')"
sops -d  --kms $(terraform output -raw kms_sops_key_arn) $file
```